# Wordpress site cant display media when it's live

Tags: php

In localhost this code works fine to display images from my media gallery but when my site goes live $images are empty although there are images in the media gallery.
Are there something I've missed out?

```
$images =& get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image' );

if ( empty($images) ) {
   echo "There are no logos to display.";
} else {
   foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
      echo '<div class="col-1-4">';
      echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' );
      echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you in The Loop in both tests?

Comment: None of those tests are in The Loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if there are any `localhost` strings in the production database if your are using some kind of plugin.

Are all the images showing up in your media library on the production site?

Comment: I don't use any plugin for this, jag uploading the media to that specific page.

Yes, the images are showing up in the media library, just can't grab them.

Answer (score 0):

If you've uploaded media to a page, your code is not going to retrieve those attachments, because you have not specified a `post_parent` in your `get_children` arguments, so it will default to `0`, or attachments with no parent.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with this code, thanks for the help!

```
        $gallery = get_children( 'posts_per_page=5&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . $post->ID );
        $attr = array(
            'class' => "attachment-$size wp-post-image",
        );
        foreach( $gallery as $image ) {

             echo '<div class="col-1-4 text-center">';
             echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, $attachment_id);
             echo "</div>";
        }
```

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful.